# How can I change the size of dmesg ? [linux 2.4]

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm writing some code with printk [i'm printing while in kernel mode] ,
but because dmesg is too small I'm losing the first few printk's.

How can I increase the size of dmesg ?

thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set `CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT` [during compile time](http://oguzhanozmen.blogspot.com/2008/09/kernel-log-buffering-printk-syslog-ng.html). The size of the buffer can not be modified in run time.

The size of the buffer is `2^CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT` bytes

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like this is only available in `2.6` series of kernels.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `log_buf_len` kernel parameter at boot time to set the kernel's `printk()` ring buffer size.

See: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt

(You mentioned Linux 2.4; I don't know whether `log_buf_len` was present in Linux 2.4, which is very old.)

Answer (score 1):

Printk is implemented by using a ring buffer in the kernel with a size of `__LOG_BUF_LEN` bytes where `__LOG_BUF_LEN` equals (`1 << CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT`) (see kernel/printk.c for details).

You can specify the size of the buffer in your kernel config by setting `CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT` to an appropriate value (e.g. 17 for 128Kb) (`make menuconfig -> General Setup -> Kernel log buffer size`).

Reference:https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing